# Output in email body is repeating itself

Tags: html, powershell

I have executed my script and I am getting the output results.

Suppose I am checking ping status for 5 servers, then for the very first time I am running the script then in mail body I am getting the output of 5 servers only, but second time I am running the same script it is giving output in mail body but it is also showing the first results as well.

If I run the script again it will display same results three times and so on, like below:

How can I remove this repetition over email body?

Output which I am getting:

```
1.2.3.4.5 could not find host
X is success
Y is failed
Z is success
H is failed
1.2.3.4.5 could not find host
X is failed
Y is failed
Y is failed
Z is failed
H is failed
```

Output which I am expecting to display during that time:

```
1.2.3.4.5 could not find host
X is success
Y is failed
Z is success
H is failed
```

Script:

```
cls
$ip = Get-Content -Path 'D:\ping text.txt'

foreach ( $ip1 in $ip ) { 
    $ip2 = ping $ip1

    if ( $ip2 -imatch "(100% loss)")

    { 
        Write-Host "$ip1 is failed" -ForegroundColor Red
        $output="$ip1 is failed"

    }

    elseif ($ip2 -imatch "Ping request could not find host")

    {
        Write-Host "$ip1 could not find host" -ForegroundColor Red
        $output = "$ip1 could not find host"
    }

    else

    {
        Write-Host "$ip1 is success" -ForegroundColor Green
        $output="$ip1 is success"
    }

   $output | Out-File "D:\result.html" -append 
}

$body += Clear-Content [System.IO.File]::ReadAllText("D:\result.html")

Send-MailMessage -From 'X' -To 'Y' -Subject 'Sending the Attachment' -Body  $body  -Attachments D:\result.html -Priority High  -SmtpServer 'webmail.wipro.com' -Port 587
```

Comment: Hi sir,
I have removed -append as you asked me to do but still no luck, getting the same repetitive output over email body

Comment: @mplungjan sir and also getting the below error in terminal


Clear-Content : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument 'D:\result.html'.
At line:32 char:10
+ $body += Clear-Content [System.IO.File]::ReadAllText("D:\result.html" ...
+          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Clear-Content], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PositionalParameterNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ClearContentCommand

Comment: Okay sir, but do i need to delete the output file everytime before running the script?

Comment: actuaaly i am getting a bit confused, sorry but i am not that pro, so can u pls edit those line which i need to edit and also where to put that into. That would help!!

Comment: Also, appending lines to a (text) file and calling that `.HTML` will not display properly. The Newline in HTML is `<br />` not CRLF

Comment: Hi @Theo can u please elaborate

Comment: Your file `D:\result.html` is nothing more that a plain text file. By naming it `.HTML` doesn't make it valid Html and if you open that in a browser all lines will be concatenated into one single line of text. I would suggest not to bother with an attachment at all, but add the information in the body of the email itself.

Comment: Also, have a look at what [Test-Connection or Test-NetConnection](https://4sysops.com/archives/test-netconnection-vs-test-connection-testing-a-network-connection-with-powershell/) can do for you instead of trying to find strings in the returned lines of `ping`. With ping, you will have to know all different messages and for one, you have left out `"Destination host unreachable."`

Comment: @Theo yea i got your point, but now the question is how can i view the output directly into the mail body itself, bcz i am facing a bit difficulty in getting it into the mail body, please suggest further on this

Comment: and moreover  output which i am getting over mail body it is showing the previous values as well. suppose if am getting output as A,B. So second time when i am running the script i should get the output as A,B    not     A,B,A,B, So this is what it is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To continue from my comments, I woud not try to create a file and send that as attachment, but rather add the results in the email body.

This prevents your error that earlier output in the attachment is kept because you append messages to a file without removing it first.
Also, `Out-File` does not create a HTML file unless you add the HTML tags, newlines etc, to the messages yourself.

Also, for the receiver of the email, it is nicer because they do not have to click to open an attached file.

Try

```
# read the list of IP addresses making sure duplicates are removed
$ipAddresses = Get-Content -Path 'D:\ping text.txt' | Select-Object -Unique

# loop through the IP addresses and test them. Collect the results in variable $output
$output = foreach ( $ip in $ipAddresses ) { 
    try {
        $null = Test-Connection -ComputerName $ip -Count 1 -ErrorAction Stop
        Write-Host "$ip is OK" -ForegroundColor Green
        # output an object with the IP and the Success message
        ###################################################################
        # If you DO NOT want Succes lines in the results and therefore also 
        # not in the email body, then comment out this next line 
        ###################################################################
        [PsCustomObject]@{IP = $ip; Message = 'Success'}
    }
    catch {
        Write-Host "$ip failed" -ForegroundColor Red
        # output an object with the IP and the failure message
        [PsCustomObject]@{IP = $ip; Message = $_.Exception.Message}
    }
}

# show the results as table in the email message
# for HTML mail, either build a nice CSS style and use something like
#  $body = $output | ConvertTo-Html -Title ('Connection Test {0:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss}' -f (Get-Date))

# as demo here, format the result as table and wrap that in '<pre>..</pre>' tags 
# so it wil show up with a monospaced font, looking the same as in the console. 
$body = '<pre>{0}</pre>' -f ($output | Format-Table -AutoSize | Out-String -Width 4096)

# best use Splatting on cmdlets that take a lot of parameters:
$mailParams = @{
    From       = 'you@yourcompany.com'
    To         = 'someone@yourcompany.com'
    Subject    = 'Connection Test {0:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss}' -f (Get-Date)
    Body       = $body
    BodyAsHtml = $true
    Priority   = 'High'
    SmtpServer = 'webmail.wipro.com'
    Port       = 587
    # more parameters go here
}
# send the email
Send-MailMessage @mailParams
```

---

As requested some explanation to the above:

The `foreach` loop iterates over the (unique) set of IP addresses and by prefixing that loop with `$output =`, everything that outputs something inside the loop gets captures (collected) in that variable.
`Write-Host` only sends output to console screen, so there is nothing that gets collected from that.
What you DO want to output is an **object** with two properties: 'IP' and 'Message'.

To create such an object real easy, use [PsCustomObject](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/learn/deep-dives/everything-about-pscustomobject)

You output this when the ping ([Test-Connection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/test-connection) by default uses ping in the background) is successful, but **also** when an error occurs.

You handle both success and error in a `try{..} catch{..}` construct and for that to catch all exceptions, you need to add `-ErrorAction Stop` to the cmdlet that can throw an exception.
If all goes well, only the code inside `try{..}` gets executed. Only if an error occurs, the code inside the `catch{..}` gets executed.

As I have commented earlier, there can be a lot of different error messages, all happily returned to you inside the `catch{..}` in the `$_.Exception.Message` property, so there is no need to try and spell these out yourself. (`$_` is an [Automatic variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_automatic_variables) that inside a `catch` represents the exception object itself)

Why this doesn't repeat output from earlier runs is because we are not **appending** to a file, but instead collect everything in memory in a (re) new `$output` variable.

Please read the links I gave for better understanding.

---

---

Although nothing like this was in your original question, to gather more properties, you could try this instead

```
try {
    Write-Host "$ip is OK" -ForegroundColor Green
    # output an object with the IP and the Success message
    Test-Connection -ComputerName $ip -Count 1 -ErrorAction Stop |
    Select-Object @{Name = 'Source'; Expression = {$env:COMPUTERNAME}}, 
                  @{Name = 'Destination'; Expression = {$ip}}, 
                  IPV4Address, IPV6Address, 
                  @{Name = 'Bytes'; Expression = {$_.BufferSize}}, 
                  @{Name = 'Time(ms)'; Expression = {$_.ResponseTime}},
                  @{Name = 'Message'; Expression = {'Success'}}
}
catch {
    Write-Host "$ip failed" -ForegroundColor Red
    # output an object with the IP and the failure message
    [PsCustomObject]@{
        Source      = $env:COMPUTERNAME
        Destination = $_.TargetObject
        IPV4Address = $null
        IPV6Address = $null
        Bytes       = $null
        'Time(ms)'  = $null
        Message     = $_.Exception.Message
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lottt sir, it was an honor to be guided by you and script is working absolutely fine.

Comment: sir one thing i want to ask is when you are directly fetching the output to mail body so through which command it is not duplicating its output like the way i used to get my previous output details along with the current one. and also what does the below two command indicates

[PsCustomObject]@{IP = $ip; Message = 'Success'}
try and catch

if you can explain a bit of it, it would be helpful for me

Comment: and also how it is able to detect the bad host name, bcz it is surprising, please explain this to me

Comment: Thank you @Theo Sir, it will be helpful for me for better understanding how this script is designed. I will wait...

Comment: @Dark Please see my edit which hpefully explains what the code is doing

Comment: Sure i will check on that sir, just out of curiosity i want to know is there any way in which i can keep my script password protected however it can run without any issue if i schedule it through task scheduler and it should not ask for any password after its scheduled in task scheduler , its only just that no-one can view my script or edits it (ps1 file), Please suggest on this as well and please let me know which command to use  @Theo Sir

Comment: Sir, i just noticed that the output that i am getting is at times of different format and at times the format is getting changed

Comment: IP              Message                                                                               
--              -------                                                                               
AZSG-D-SCUX-P Testing connection to computer 'AZSG-D-SCUAPP-N' failed: No such host is known

Comment: Can u pls explain why it is coming like this as i am running the same script. Thanks in Advance!!
@Theo Sir

Comment: Second type of output

Source       Destination     IPV4Address   IPV6Address Bytes Time(ms)
------         -----------     -----------   ----------- ----- --------
APL-5C12345PY AZSG-P-DIGTZZA 10.235.2.1              32    152     
Host    : AZSG-P-DIGTZZA
Message : Success

Comment: @Dark Ok, I see what you mean. That is unwanted output from Test-Connection itself (a Win32_PingStatus object) which we don't want in our $output. I have now blocked that kind of output using `$null = Test-Connection`

Comment: Okay i got ur point but incase i want that output so what do i need to use because i have used test-connection to test google.com and it is showing me the source, IPV4 address, destination, bytes and Time(ms), so if i want this forma what i need to do, bcz i have runned the same previous script which was provided by you but it was giving the same results along with the one which i mentioned earlier

Comment: so pls let me know how can it vary with the same script i mean the output bcz at times it was showing me only the IP and results parallely but previously it was showing me with Source, Destination, IPV4Address, IPV6Address, Bytes, Time(ms)

Comment: Requesting you to please clarify this for me, i know u have helped a lot and i truly respect that seriously i want to learn this basic logic, so please let me know why i was getting two different output as i said earlier one only with IP and message ; and the other was with  Source, Destination, IPV4Address, IPV6Address, Bytes, Time(ms), and now pls let me know how can i display in my mail body   Source, Destination, IPV4Address, IPV6Address, Bytes, Time(ms),

Comment: Sir please, as i want Source, Destination, IPV4Address, IPV6Address, Bytes, Time(ms) to be displayed as i was getting earlier with your very first edit

Comment: so if i remove that $null so i believe it will display Source, Destination, IPV4Address, IPV6Address, Bytes, Time(ms) in output

Comment: @Dark Please see my final edit

Comment: Thanks @Theo Sir i just executed script however the message is displayed perfectly fine for success and failed in mail body along with the rest of the parameters however for "no host found" the output is displaying as <Testing connection to computer 'SG-BPSC13-P-AP1' failed: No  such host is known> which is perfectly fine, but the same is not arranged it is showing 2 words are on right, 3 on middle and few on left side in the mail body.Like the below Not sure if you can view the below example properly or not

Comment: APL-5CD901234u SG-BPSr02-P-DB2 10.235.1.2                 32      150 Success                                                      

APL-5CD901234u SG-BPSC13-P-PS1                                          Testing connection to computer 'SG-BPSC13-P-PS1' failed: No  
                                                                        such host is known                                           
                                         

@Theo Sir

Comment: Actually the output for No host found in message column is not organised, the words are showing some of left, some at middle and some at right so it will become difficult for any user to read the output

Comment: Hope u can understand @Theo sir what exactly i mean to say, i dont have any option to share screenshot or else i would have shared it for better understanding

Comment: @Dark, then take off `-Wrap`. PLease, This is really the last I will comment or edit on this question. Try figuring out yourself what cmdlets like `Format-Table` do, what switches they have etc.

Comment: Sure @Theo Sir pls edit this for the last time for this issue and lastly Thanks a lott for all your guidance bcz this wouldnt have been came so far without your help :)

Comment: @Dark Ok, I have changed `($output | Format-Table -AutoSize -Wrap | Out-String)` to `($output | Format-Table -AutoSize | Out-String -Width 4096)` to not wrap the long items around, but instead allow for more width

Comment: Hi @Theo Sir, Hope you are doing well, today was my presentation for my project for the script which you helped me to prepare however it went well, moreover there is a small modification which my team is asking which is they dont want the success to be displayed in mail body and the only thing that they want is the Failed and the bad host-name to be displayed in mail body  i am uncertain how to do that. I know you said earlier that you wont be replying but if u can just help me in this how can i only display the Failed and Bad hostname in mail body not the servers which is success then it help

Comment: @Dark: may I suggest you write a new question for that?

Answer (score 0):

Delete the file you are appending to before appending

Please correct the script if it gives errors. I do not normally script powershell

```
cls
$ip = Get-Content -Path 'D:\ping text.txt'

$fileName = "D:\result.html"

if (Test-Path $FileName = True) {
  Remove-Item $FileName
}

foreach ( $ip1 in $ip ) { 
    $ip2 = ping $ip1

    if ( $ip2 -imatch "(100% loss)")

    { 
        Write-Host "$ip1 is failed" -ForegroundColor Red
        $output="$ip1 is failed"

    }

    elseif ($ip2 -imatch "Ping request could not find host")

    {
        Write-Host "$ip1 could not find host" -ForegroundColor Red
        $output = "$ip1 could not find host"
    }

    else

    {
        Write-Host "$ip1 is success" -ForegroundColor Green
        $output="$ip1 is success"
    }

   $output | Out-File $fileName -append 
}

$body += Clear-Content [System.IO.File]::ReadAllText($fileName)

Send-MailMessage -From 'X' -To 'Y' -Subject 'Sending the Attachment' -Body  $body  -Attachments $fileName -Priority High  -SmtpServer 'webmail.wipro.com' -Port 587
```